# Native resource cleanup and Not calling Dispose

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Can anyone explain why not calling Dispose() explicitly, and native resource still gets cleaned up. Does it get called implicitly?

I came cross below

> calling Dispose is not required to guarantee native resource cleanup.
>   Native  resource cleanup will always happen eventually; calling
>   Dispose lets you control when that cleanup  happens.

```
  // Create the bytes to write to the temporary file.  
  Byte[] bytesToWrite = new Byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };  

  // Create the temporary file.  
  FileStream fs = new FileStream("Temp.dat", FileMode.Create);  

  // Write the bytes to the temporary file.  
  fs.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);  

  // Explicitly close the file when finished writing to it.  
  //fs.Dispose();
```

Dispose should be called explicitly in code within finally block or via using statement.

Comment: Whoever down voted this thread should give an explanation. This is not an easy search-and-get-answer kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileStream` contains [Finalize method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.finalize?view=netframework-4.7) which calls `Dispose` inside:

```
~FileStream()
{
    if (_handle != null) {
        BCLDebug.Correctness(_handle.IsClosed, "You didn't close a FileStream & it got finalized.  Name: \""+_fileName+"\"");
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Which means it will be eventually called by Finalizer when the object will not be longer reachable. Of course, it is good to call `Dispose` explictly as it let's you control cleanup deterministicaly as you've mentioned.

Comment: I forget the finalizer method. How do I find out who answer the fininalizer first between @Nikolaus and you?

Comment: I think I pick you as both code and explanation are provided.

Comment: UpVote for the link

Answer (score 1):

The garbageCollector is cleaning up unreferenced Objects, when it gets resources of the OS, but if you have a highly frequented Application it might be useful not to have to wait for it, because otherwise your memory gets filled up. Then the usage of Dispose is quite necessary.

Update:
The objects do not even need to implement IDisposable to be cleaned up, because it's the Finalize-Method that is called.

Comment: I forget the finalizer method. How do I find out who answer the fininalizer first between you and @Konrad Kokosa?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I pick @Konrad  as both code and explanation are provided.

Comment: Oh you mean for accepting the answer. You can accept what you want, but Finalizer and Finalize-Method are not really the same. Especially when a class doesn't implement IDisposable.